# Distributed Cache (Redis) in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to setup Distributed Cache in .NET Core using Redis.

I am able to get it implemented but I am having trouble figuring out how to store POCO objects.

In every example I've seen they are storing and retrieving strings. What about more complex data types:

```
public async Task<string> Get()
{
    var cacheKey = "TheTime";
    var existingTime = _distributedCache.GetString(cacheKey);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingTime))
    {
        return "Fetched from cache : " + existingTime;
    }
    else
    {
        existingTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
        _distributedCache.SetString(cacheKey, existingTime);
        return "Added to cache : " + existingTime;
    }
}
```

I assume I'll need to serialize the objects in json then store the strings? Unless there is another way.

Thank you!

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. We need to serialize the object as json!

Answer (score 6):

IDistributedCache stores byte[] and .Net Core 2.0 supports [binary serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization) so I imagine this would be the most efficient form of storage (instead of JSON).  I haven't tested this with Redis but it should work:

First add the `Serializable` attribute to the POCO:

```
[Serializable]
public class Poco {
    ...
}
```

Then to serialize it use the `BinaryFormatter`:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, model);
    var bytes = stream.ToArray();
    cache.Set("cache key", bytes);
}
```

And to deseralize:

```
var bytes = cache.get("cache key");
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
    var model = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream) as Poco;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting cache:

```
var serializedPoco = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(poco);
var  encodedPoco = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedPoco);
await distributedCache.SetAsync(cacheKey, encodedPoco, options);
```

Getting cache:

```
var encodedPoco = await distributedCache.GetAsync(cacheKey); 
var serializedPoco = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedPoco);

//change the type according to the poco object you are using 
var poco = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeof(Poco)>(serializedPoco);
```

Answer (score 0):

`IDistributedCache` is `byte[]` based, although extension methods allow you to use strings, because it is a generic interface designed to support many over-the-wire protocols.  As a result, you are responsible for serializing your own objects.